# Paramiko error in Linux:" ImportError:Unable to import a GSS-API/SSPI module"

Tags: python, paramiko, gssapi

I met this problem in my machine,and I spent several hours in solving this,I hope it can help others if they meet the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Unix: `pip install python-gssapi`.

For Windows: `pip install pywin32`.

For more information, check [here](http://www.paramiko.org/installing.html#gssapi)

In addition, if you get an error about 
**"attribute error: 'module' object has no attribute 'gssexception'"**
, maybe you have installed a wrong gssapi, remove your gssapi firstly(by `pip uninstall gssapi`) and install gssapi as previous mentioned.